# How to execute node (console) command from javascript file on click via ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Im new to node.js and this is my question:

For example: I got web application and from that application I have a button and on button click I want to run node console command (for example: node socket.io).

So:

```
$( ".button" ).on( "click", function() {
   //run ajax to node with command for example "node socket.io"
 });
```

So in this example I want to start socket.io from web javascript file.  How to do it ? I know its very basic question but I want to understand how to do it or is it even possible.

**EDIT**

But is it possible to run ajax request with that node command to node.js and then fire up it up ("node socket.io")?

**Im asking this because I want to start and stop socket.io from web application, not from console command directly.**

Comment: As nodejs runs on the server, you can't achieve this by running a command on the client. Think of nodejs as a replacement for php or RoR, or some other backend technology. You need to set up a socket connection between client and server and then fire events that are listened to on both ends.

Comment: But is it possible to run ajax request to node.js and then fire up a node command ("node socket.io")?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'd first need to start a server that receives this request (e.g. `node remote-start.js`) anyway, so why not just start socket.io directly?

Comment: I thought of that to save server resources (cpu/ram). So when I need socket.io functionality I just start it form a web app interface and when I don't need it i can turn it off from a web app interface as well . Maybe I am lacking some knowledge and my thinking about node + socket.io application is not correct - that way Im asking that kind of question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need an express route like this:

```
...

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.post('/exec', function(req, res) {
  var cmd = req.body.command;

  exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (stderr || error) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        error: stderr || error,
        command: cmd,
        result: null
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
        success: true,
        error: null,
        command: cmd,
        result: stdout
      })
    }
  })


})

...
```

*note*: stderr and stdout are [buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

You then need to `POST` your command (using AJAX or a form) to `/exec`. Which will give you a response such as:

Success:

```
{
  success: true,
  error: null,
  command: "ls",
  result: "app.js bin node_modules package.json public routes views "
}
```

Failure:

```
{
    success: false,
    error: "/bin/sh: foobar: command not found ",
    command: "foobar",
    result: null
}
```

You need to be ***extremely*** careful with security having something like this though as you are opening up access to your system's console.

Comment: This suppose to be available to only one user - super admin.

Comment: Still, it's considerably harder to access a system secured using `ssh` than it is to access an admin page. You need to make sure it's secured to attacks such as [csrf](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). If this answer is correct, make sure you mark it as a solution, thanks.

Comment: I will be aware of that. Really thank you for your answer. I will test it at and then mark it as correct answer :).

Comment: I've updated my answer to respond with JSON, which is probably easier to work with if you're using AJAX. Also, on my initial answer I used `req.param.command` which should have been `req.body.command`, and the route should have just been `/exec`, not `/exec/:command`. These changes are reflected in my edit.