# restart node js server with a button click from front end

Tags: html, node.js

I have created a simple app with Nodejs and express that shows data fetched from an API.
I want to create a button in the frontend that should restart Node Server.
Is this possible conceptually? if not, Do we have workaround?

Comment: Use a process manager such as `pm2` with auto restarts, and call `process.exit()` in the express endpoint.

Comment: Have a look at this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034997/how-to-execute-node-console-command-from-javascript-file-on-click-via-ajax

Comment: I think this link contains the solution to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666696/restart-a-node-js-app-from-code-level